# Calculate vacation days accumulated

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a 2007 MS Access database that I use and I want to add a subform that shows vacation calculations based on the employee among other things. I have a module I use that I found on the net that calculates the elapsed time between two dates and gives a result like 1 Year 2 Months 3 Days or 2 Years ect. I need to have the result give me vacation weeks instead of years, months and days. in my query it will be based on [DateOfHire] and Date()

- 1 year Service = 1 week vacation
- 2 year Service = 2 week vacation
- 8 year Service = 3 week vacation
- 15 year Service = 4 week vacation
- 25 year Service = 5 week vacation

-

```
Public Function fElapsedTimeYMD(varStartDate As Variant, varEndDate) As String

    Dim dtToday As Date
    Dim intStartYear As Integer, intStartMonth As Integer, intStartDay As Integer
    Dim intEndYear As Integer, intEndMonth As Integer, intEndDay As Integer
    Dim intTmpYear As Integer, intTmpMonth As Integer, intTmpDay As Integer
    Dim strYear As String, strMonth As String, strDay As String
    Dim sngLeap As Single

    If Not IsDate(varStartDate) Or Not IsDate(varEndDate) Then Exit Function

    dtToday = Date
    intStartYear = Year(varStartDate)
    intStartMonth = Month(varStartDate)
    intStartDay = Day(varStartDate)
    intEndYear = Year(varEndDate)
    intEndMonth = Month(varEndDate)
    intEndDay = Day(varEndDate)

    If intStartDay > intEndDay Then
        Select Case intEndMonth
        Case Is = 1
            intEndDay = intEndDay + 31
            intEndMonth = 12
            intEndYear = intEndYear - 1
        Case Is = 2    ' Check for Leap Year
            If varStartDate = DateSerial(intEndYear, 2, 29) Then
                intEndDay = intEndDay + 29
                intEndMonth = intEndMonth - 1
            Else
                intEndDay = intEndDay + 28
                intEndMonth = intEndMonth - 1
            End If
        Case Is = 4, 6, 9, 11
            intEndDay = intEndDay + 30
            intEndMonth = intEndMonth - 1
        Case Is = 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
            intEndDay = intEndDay + 31
            intEndMonth = intEndMonth - 1
        End Select
    End If

    If intStartMonth > intEndMonth Then
        Select Case intEndMonth
        Case Is = 1
            intEndMonth = 13
            intEndYear = intEndYear - 1
        Case Else
            intEndMonth = intEndMonth + 12
            intEndYear = intEndYear - 1
        End Select
    End If

    intTmpYear = intEndYear - intStartYear
    intTmpMonth = intEndMonth - intStartMonth
    intTmpDay = intEndDay - intStartDay

    Select Case intTmpYear
    Case Is = 0
        strYear = ""
    Case Is = 1
        strYear = Trim(Str(intTmpYear)) & " Year"
    Case Else
        strYear = Trim(Str(intTmpYear)) & " Years"
    End Select

    Select Case intTmpMonth
    Case Is = 0
        strMonth = ""
    Case Is = 1
        strMonth = Trim(Str(intTmpMonth)) & " Month"
    Case Else
        strMonth = Trim(Str(intTmpMonth)) & " Months"
    End Select

    Select Case intTmpDay
    Case Is = 0
        strDay = ""
    Case Is = 1
        strDay = Trim(Str(intTmpDay)) & " Day"
    Case Else
        strDay = Trim(Str(intTmpDay)) & " Days"
    End Select

    fElapsedTimeYMD = Trim(strYear & " " & strMonth & " " & strDay)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TotalVacWeeks: IIf([YearsOfService]<=0,0,IIf([YearsOfService]<=1,1,IIf([YearsOfService]<=7,2,IIf([YearsOfService]<=14,3,IIf([YearsOfService]<=24,4,IIf([YearsOfService]>=25,5))))))+IIf([BoughtVac]=True,1,0)
```

Comment: Works perfectly in my query, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a datediff

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

do a select case, Based on the duration boundaries then return an integer for the week vacation available

If you added this you should get the years.

```
Dim yearsService As Integer
yearsService = DateDiff ("yyyy", varStartDate , varEndDate)
```

This should result in an integer result

Comment: Well right now if I put in a query AccumVacWeeks: fElapsedTimeYMD([EmpDateOfHire], Date()) in my query it will show me based on how long the employee worked there in years, months and days if there is any. Im sorry but im not understanding where I would do a select case? If I did a bunch of IIFs in the query I would get an error because the function gives me a result of a number and text.

Comment: If you execute this for example,   DateDiff ("yyyy", #15/10/1998#, #22/11/2003#) is should result in a integer of 5 being returned and not a string

Comment: I understand that but im not getting what your trying to do? The function gives a result not in that date format it gives it in "1 Year 5 Months 1 Day".

Comment: (cc: @SoggyCashew) Be aware that `DateDiff("yyyy", ...)` does not count *whole* years based on month and day, it essentially does `Year(endDate) - Year(startDate)`. For example, `DateDiff ("yyyy", #1998-12-31#, #1999-01-01#)` returns 1, even though the difference between the two dates is only one *day*, not a full year.

Comment: VacWeeksEarned2: IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=0,0,IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=1,1,IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=7,2,IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=14,3,IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=24,4,IIf(DateDiff('yyyy',[EmpDateOfHire],Date())<=25,5))))))   I can use it this way...